# What mistake am I making within this logic resolution problem?

Tags: logic

I'm given the following statements:

> $$M_1\implies O$$$$\neg M_1 \implies Z$$$$(O\lor Z)\implies H$$$$H\implies M_2$$

Then the question is, can you prove whether H is true? Followed up by, now answer the same question via logical resolution.

My solution:

> Consider case $M_1$:
>               $$
>    \nonumber M_1\implies O \implies H
>    $$
>               Case $\neg M_1$:
>               $$
>    \neg M_1 \implies Z\implies H.
>    $$
>   So that $H$ is a tautology.

With resolution:

> First, let us rewrite to CNF:         \begin{align*}    &(\neg O \lor M)
>  \land (\neg Z \lor \neg M_1) \land (\neg H \lor M_1 \lor Z) \land (\neg M_2\lor H)   \end{align*}      Then for $H$, we simply add the clause $\neg
>  H$ and see if this is satisfiable:        \begin{align*}    &(\neg O \lor
>  M_1) \land (\neg Z \lor \neg M_1) \land (\neg H \lor M_1 \lor Z) \land (\neg
>  M_2 \lor H)\land \neg H\\    \implies&(\neg O \lor \neg Z) \land (\neg H
>  \lor M_1 \lor Z) \land \neg M_2\\    \implies&(\neg O \lor \neg H \lor M_1)
>  \land \neg M_2\\   \end{align*}      This is satisfiable, so $H$ is not a
>    tautology.

But this is of course a contradiction so hence my question: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, they are different. It's an unfortunate naming scheme. I'll change quickly adapt it for clarity.

Comment: The first part is right: $M \lor \lnot M$ holds and thus, from 1) and 2) we get:  $O \lor Z$. Thus, from 3) we derive: $H$.

Comment: This does not mean that $H$ is a *tautology* : it is **not**. It means that 1), 2) and 3) (and 4)) *imply* $H$.

Comment: Where is the mistake ? As you can see in the answer below, the *clauses* are wrongly written.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Conjunctive Normal Form. The V is for the Dutch variant, forgot to take it out :) Here a tautology means: a tautology within the model where all given clauses are necessarily true. Perhaps it's the wrong term, but I found it most resembled what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *clauses* must be:

> 1) $\lnot M \lor O$
>
> 2) $M \lor Z$

For: >$\lnot (O \lor Z) \lor H$, that is: $(\lnot O \land \lnot Z) \lor H$ that is: $(\lnot O \lor H) \land (\lnot Z \lor H)$. Thus:

> 3) $\lnot O \lor H$
>
> 4) $\lnot Z \lor H$
>
> 5) $\lnot H \lor N$.

---

In order to apply [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), you have to add to the set of *premises* the negation of the conclusion, i.e.

> 6) $\lnot H$.

*Resolution*:

7) $O \lor Z$ --- from 1) and 2)

8) $Z \lor H$ --- from 7) and 3)

9) $H$ --- from 8) and 4)

> > $\square$ (the *empty clause*) --- from 9) and 6).

---

As you can see, the last premise is inessential for the proof.

Comment: I'm supposed to do the same with $m$ ($M_2$) now, but I can't seem to resolve this one without also adding $H$ or $\neg M$ as clause. Are you allowed to do that, or do you just have to keep searching until you find a way? What are some good resolution finding strategies?

Comment: @MitchellFaas - In that case you have to remove 6) $\lnot H$ and add 6') $\lnot M_2$ (for me: $\lnot N$).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. But with doing that, I still didn't manage to find the solution. Is there some trick to finding the right one? My idea was that I wanted to find a way to work away $\neg H \lor N$, but I couldn't do it. EDIT: And just now I found it.. Thanks :)

Comment: @MitchellFaas - the proof is similar; from 9) $H$  with 5) we get $N$ that conclude with 6') $\lnot N$.

Comment: Resolution is developed for automatic theorem proving: it's an algorithm. Check all combinations. When used by humans, use insight.